# Git checkout to specified commit doesn't ignore previous commit?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

When I do `git checkout 10bec0c` with the intention of wanting to ONLY the last changes (3) but why 1 and 2 is included? I use cherry-pick it's also the same. How to get only a specified ONE commit?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please, try creating a branch for the commit by `git checkout 10bec0c temp_branch` then inspect logs by `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`.

Comment: I think the issue is I create a new branch base on an existing branch which contain another commits, now how do I remove commit 1,2 without doing manual code remove?

Comment: I did this, commit 1 and 2 is still there

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you mean by "get" (as in *get* a specified commit).

The key here is that each Git commit holds a full and complete snapshot of *every* file, as of the form that file had at the time you (or whoever) *made* the commit.<sup>1</sup>  In other words, commits *do not store changes*.

Using `git checkout` or `git switch --detach` to check out a particular commit simply *extracts that commit*, so that the files you have in your working tree, where you get to see and work on / with your files, are the files that are stored in that snapshot, as they existed on that day and time.

You can, however, *view* a commit *as* changes.  This works because every commit remembers the raw hash ID of its immediate predecessor commit (or commits, for a merge commit).  Depending on which way your viewer ordered the three commits it displayed here:

```
<image> 1     ff5cbab
<image> 2  ✅ 26b5656
<image> 3  ✅ 10bec0c
```

the predecessor (or parent) of `26b5656` is either `ff5cbab` or `10bec0c`.  I'll assume it's `ff5cbab` here, i.e., the commits go:

```
... <-ff5cbab     <-26b5656     <-10bec0c [latest]
```

and that your viewer shows them "upside down" as compared to, say, `git log --graph`, which would show the latest *first*, instead of *last*.

If this is the case, the command `git show 26b5656` causes Git to:

- find commit `26b5656`;
- inspect the backwards-pointing arrow coming out of it to find the *previous* (or *parent*) commit `ff5cbab`;
- use those two hash IDs to extract *both* commits to a temporary (memory) area; and then
- *compare* those two commits' snapshots.

For each file that is *the same* in each commit, this comparison says nothing at all.  For each file that is *different*, Git computes some way to *convert* the older file to the newer one.  This is a *diff*, i.e., a recipe for changing one file into another.  Git then shows you the file's name and the recipe.

You can get a diff between *any pair of commits* using `git diff`, by giving it both commit hash IDs.  If you pick the parent-and-child pair and use the hash IDs in the order:

```
git diff <parent> <child>
```

you get a recipe for turning the parent commit *into* the child commit.  If you reverse these:

```
git diff <child> <parent>
```

you get a recipe for turning the child into the parent—i.e., a recipe by which you can "undo" the commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>These snapshots are stored in a special Git-only format, in which files are compressed—sometimes highly compressed—and de-duplicated.  So if you have a million commits, each of which contains a 10 megabyte file, but the 10 megabyte file is identical in all million commits, those one million 10 MB files consume ... 10 MB, or even less if the compression is good.  It doesn't take the implied 10 terabytes, because it's been *de-duplicated* 999999 times.

Comment: if I merge the commit 1 and 2 into master, it doesn't matter the history of 1 and 2 is there with 3  right?

Comment: @AliciaY: if you mean you're going to run `git merge`: you need to *draw the graph* (`git log --graph` or similar; see [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452)) and locate the two *branch tip* commits and then use the graph to find the *merge base* commit. Git is going to use these three commits as the three snapshots that are inputs to the merge. The "history of 1 and 2" are relevant to finding the *merge base commit*, but after that point, are not relevant at all any more.